# How can one turn off curl's AsynchDNS in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I have suspicions curl's AsynchDNS is causing me problems, and I'd like to turn it off, but I can't seem to find any clear method of doing that. Is there a php.ini setting I can use to disable it? If so, what is it?

Comment: think you need to replace your curl with a curl without A-DNS

Comment: I tried replacing a copy of libcurl.dylib (along with some aliases ie: libcurl.4.dylib) from my old MacBook to my new one, and it actually crashed Lion! So much that I'm having to reinstall it. I'm thinking that the crash may have been because I moved the alias files, but I'm wondering if 'libcurl.dylib' is even the correct file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't just disable it, it is a build-time option so you have to rebuild libcurl from the source code.

I tried replacing OS X Lion's built in libcurl library with no success, and eventually worked around the problem without disabling AsynchDNS.